# error calc bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```shell
#!/bin/bash


if [ $2 == "+" ]; then
    echo $1 + $3 | bc
elif [ $2 == "-" ]; then
 echo $1 -$3 | bc
 elif [ $2 == "/" ]; then
 echo $1 / $3 | bc -l
 elif  [ ${2: -0} == "\*" ]; then
  echo $1 \* $3 | bc
fi





[ali@localhost Desktop]$ ./q1.sh 5 \* 2
./q1.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
./q1.sh: line 6: [: too many arguments
./q1.sh: line 8: [: too many arguments
./q1.sh: line 10: [: too many arguments
```

Comment: Just a thought ..  Square brackets a shortcut for the test command --  So some special characters within a variable itself may break up the string into "multiple arguments" ...

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  It will help you write your question in a way that will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below script would do :

```
   #!/bin/bash
    if [ "$2" = "+" ] # == won't work with old test ie [],
    #use [[ ]]  if you wish to use ==
    then
     echo "$1 + $3" | bc
    elif [ "$2" = "-" ]; then
     echo "$1 - $3" | bc
    elif [ "$2" = "/" ]; then
      if [ "$3" -ne 0 ]
      then
        echo "scale=3;$1 / $3" | bc -l # scale gives the precision of the results
      else
        echo "Division by zero not possible"
      fi
    elif [ "$2" = '*' ]; then
       # You need to escape or quote the asterisk in the command line
       # when calling the script like ./script 3 \* 4
       echo "$1 * $3" | bc
    fi 2>/dev/null # For suppressing the errors when using '\*' as $2
```

**Sample Run**

```
$ ./38464438.sh 4 + 5
9
$ ./38464438.sh 4 - 5
-1
$ ./38464438.sh 4 / 5
.800
$ ./38464438.sh 4 \* 5
20
```

Comment: To the downvoter, I forgot to quote some variables which I have rectified. Is that the only reason for downvote?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
bc <<< "$@"
```

Examples:

```
q1 5 \* 2
q1 'scale=5; sqrt( 9^2 + 10^2 + 33^2 )'
```

Output:

```
10
35.63705
```

Answer (score 0):

*Always* quote your parameter expansions unless you have a very good reason not to. When `$2` is `*` (as in your example), it undergoes pathname expansion. `*` expands to every file in the current working directory, which produces far too many arguments for the `[` command.

```
if [ "$2" = "+" ]; then
```

(Also, don't use `==` with `[`; use the correct equality operator `=`.)

---

Bonus advice: Your script receives `*` as an argument, not `\*`, so your final comparison should be

```
elif  [ "$2" = "*" ]; then
```